# Generating Pseudo Columns in MySql

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have table with multiple jobs and multiple departments, I want to process the data in such way that the it will give department wise and job wise salary information. How can I achieve this? Can it be achieved using only select and case or similar?

**Input Table:**

```
+------+-----------+--------+--------+--------------+
| id   | name      | salary | deptno | job          |
+------+-----------+--------+--------+--------------+
|    1 | Lucas     |  20000 |      1 | Founder      |
|    2 | Gabriello |  18300 |      1 | Cofounder    |
|    3 | Teodoor   |  15000 |      2 | Sales        | 
|    4 | Ronna     |  12600 |      3 | Marketing    |
|    5 | Dixie     |   6800 |      3 | Janitor      |
|    6 | Kelsey    |   6400 |      2 | Janitor      |
|    7 | Tatiania  |  15200 |      2 | Sales        |
|    8 | Goldia    |  12400 |      3 | Marketing    |
+------+-----------+--------+--------+--------------+
```

**Output Table:**

```
deptno  Founder    Cofounder      Sales       Marketing   Janitor
------------------------------------------------------------------
  1      20000       18300          0             0         0
  2        0           0       15000+15200        0        6400
  3        0           0            0        12600+12400   6800
```

Comment: As a reminder, if someone gives you the answer that works, please mark it as the "accepted" answer by clicking the green checkmark next to their answer.

Comment: Upvoting because the Q and A are among the most concise for "pivot-table".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select deptno, 
       sum(case when job = 'Founder' then salary else 0 end) as Founder,
       sum(case when job = 'Cofounder' then salary else 0 end) as Cofounder,
       sum(case when job = 'Sales' then salary else 0 end) as Sales,
       sum(case when job = 'Marketing' then salary else 0 end) as Marketing,
       sum(case when job = 'Janitor' then salary else 0 end) as Janitor
from your_table
group by deptno
```